# How to count classnames of dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript

Is there something I should keep in mind when trying to count ClassNames of dynamically added elements?

For the following description, refer to the link. Upon clicking the "(+)Course" button on any Semester (which are dynamically added), a Course will be appended to the corresponding Semester, with buttons of its own. This works. However, like I have for the Semesters, I have a limit of how many of each element there can be (i.e., 5 Semesters in total, 7 Courses per Semester), but I can't seem to be able to count my Courses.

Each Semester has a unique ClassName for its Courses, which is a concatenation of the Semester's Id and the word "Course", resulting in something like "sem#4Course". This code snippet is how I assemble and count the ClassNames for each Course. Is there something wrong with it? I've attached the rest of my code in the link.

```
var parentId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
var crsClass = parentId+"Course";
var crsCount = $('.'+crsClass).length;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4efzf681/2/

I only started learning JavaScript/JQuery last week, so please bear with me. And I apologize for not separating my code between HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I work in a single file and separate it upon completion, and I've also never used fiddle before. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You want to count the number of elements which have `crsClass` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` character in your class name values `sem#1` and `sem#1Course` are creating a problem for the `$()` query selector which sees a *class* `.sem` and an *id* `#1` or `#1Course`. It is better not to use the `#` and `.` characters in your class names and IDs. Instead use hyphens and underscore characters.

The improved fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/6pdfjbt1/

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I had no idea my naming scheme was problematic. Changing them resolved my immediate issues. I'm giving you the Best Answer for the concise explanation, and because you have less points the other user.

Comment: @DevonT. Gee. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing jQuery's selector engine by adding the parents `id` attribute to your course class name. The classes will inculde `#`, guess jquery thinks you want to select an element by it's `id`.

Changed that by doing

`var crsClass = parentId.replace("#", "")+"Course";`

I fixed your fiddle. Make sure to put your js in the bottom window next time ;).
I also moved the `crsCount` variable to the bottom to assign the value after the courses have been appended to the DOM.

[**YOUR FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ahunzof3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `elements` by `class name` using javascript method `getElementsByClassName`

```
var crsCount = document.getElementsByClassName(crsClass).length;
```